# Convert popen output to list, and perform action

Tags: python, list, subprocess

```
def calc_execution():
    import subprocess
    get_pid_detectmotion = "pgrep -f detectmotion.py"
    pidcmd = subprocess.Popen(get_pid_detectmotion.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    pidcmd, error = pidcmd.communicate()
    #print pidcmd
    #detectmotion_file_pid = int(out.rstrip())
    get_length_pid_running="ps -o etime= -p" + pidcmd
    length_pid_detectmotion_running = subprocess.Popen(get_length_pid_running.split())#, int(pidcmd))
    print length_pid_detectmotion_running
    print list(length_pid_detectmotion_running)
```

Outputs:

```
TypeError: 'Popen' object is not iterable
   23:15:59
```

How can I convert the output of `length_pid_detectmotion_running` to a `list`, then get the closest value to the left, if there are (3). For example: `23:15:59` I want to print out `23` within a list like `length_pid_detectmotion_running[0]`

Comment: use `check_output` instead, and `split(":")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Popen` is useful when you want to perform some parallel tasks, like controlled/modified printing line by line while program is running, expect output

`Popen` is a structure, and not directly iterable. To get the list of lines of the process' standard output, you should convert `length_pid_detectmotion_running.stdout` to list instead.

But in your case you should just use `check_output` and split:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(get_length_pid_running.split())
toks = output.split(":")
```

first element of `toks` should be your `23`